# Sending a Post request to Flask API, but not receiving data

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

So I am trying to send certain values to my Flask API streamlit application, but it appears that it is not executing a post request. Right now, the post request code I have for my `main.py` does not work because I am getting a `TypeError: 'NoneType'`.

**app.py** :

```
import requests
import json
import streamlit as st
...
api_url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/" # Flask url
create_row_data = {'name': name, 'type': get_type(name), 'token_value': token_value, 
'external': external, 'start': start, 'end': end, 'step': step}
print(create_row_data)

# The terminal cannot print out the value of r and it appears that it cannot send the post request as well
r = requests.post(url=api_url, json = create_row_data)
print(r)
```

Output of `print(create_row_data)` in app.py:

```
{'name': 'session', 'type': 'area_chart', 'token_value': 'G0as7vjk1ksuxn94', 
'external': False, 'start': datetime.datetime(2021,7,1,14,9,7,322438), 'end': datetime.datetime(2021,7,8,14,9,7,322441), 'step': '1d'}
```

**main.py**:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask import request
...
import requests, json
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_data():
   if request.method == 'GET':
       return "ok", 200
   if request.method =='POST':
      p_name = request.json['name']
      p_type = request.json['type']
      ...
      p_end = request.json['end']
      p_step = request.json['step']
      create_row_data = {'p_name': str(p_name), 'p_type': str(p_type), ... , 'p_end': str(p_end), 'p_step': str(p_step)}
      print(create_row_data)  
      response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(create_row_data), headers= {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
      return response.content
```

Comment: you are setting api_url as "ok" and not the http://127.0.0.1:5000/ remove the get method while setting api_url.

Comment: Hi @darthbaba, I am still returning the same error even though I have removed the request.get()

Comment: In main.py create a response dict like response = request.json() and then set p_name = response['name'] and so on.

Comment: Hi @darthbaba, I just tried that as well and I am getting a `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable` for `response=request.json()`.

Comment: you are trying to post from app.py to main.py right? and then again from main.py to where?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to post from app.py to main.py. And then I would like dictionary to be printed on `127.0.01:5000` as a json format if that is possible. What I am trying to do next is extract certain values to produce a table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234673/discussion-between-darth-baba-and-sl42).

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you need to post data to 127.0.0.1 and process it to create a table from app.py using flask_restful to create an API endpoint so that you can post data. The code for main.py would be:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask import jsonify
from flask import request
import requests, json

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_data():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return "ok", 200

class create_row_data(Resource):
    def post(self):
        response = request.get_json()
        p_name = response['name']
        p_type = response['type']
        ...
        # code to process your data and to create a table

        # return something for your client application
        return True    

api.add_resource(create_row_data, '/create_row_data/')
```

No changes are needed for your client app.py except the url which now changes to http://127.0.0.1:5000/create_row_data/

Comment: Hi @darth baba. I just tested out the code you provided and now I am getting an error of werkzeug.routing.RequestRedirect: 308 Permanent Redirect: 127.0.01:5000/create_row_data. Besides changing the code for main.py, I also changed the api_url in the app.py.

Comment: add the trailing slash, the url you need to be hitting is 127.0.0.1:5000/create_row_data/